# XeLaTeX warning - objects still allocated in memory

Tags: xetex, warnings, memory

I'm typesetting a document in `XeLaTeX` and keep getting this message:

```
** WARNING ** 1735 memory objects still allocated
You may want to report this to tex-k@tug.org
```

What does it mean? Am I to worry about it?

Comment: You can ignore it because it is non-fatal. It is fixed in the upstream `dvipdfmx` code as of TeXLive-2012, afaik.

Comment: Thanks. Want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This message is produced by `xdvipdfmx`, called by XeTeX in order to produce PDF from the intermediate .xdv (extended dvi). While writing the PDF, `xdvipdfmx` dynamically allocates entities that translate into PDF objects in the output PDF file. The memory (RAM) should be properly deallocated once a PDF object has been written out and doesn't change any more. This fails somehow in older versions but doesn't affect the output PDF. In the upstream `dvipdfmx`, part of current TeXLive-2012, from which `xdvipdfmx` is derived, this bug has been fixed already. This warning message can be ignored safely.